# C# date rolling 13 months values in global variable .NET

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

In C# how do I get the below `datetime` values in .NET. I am trying to look at todays date and trying to get a rolling 13 months. So last month *minus* 13 months which is **december 2017** but need to get first day of the month at *00:00:00.000*. Also trying to get an `enddate` as below which is end of last month.

Trying to get this and assign it to a variable in my code.

StartDate:

```
2017-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

EndDate:

```
2019-01-31 23:59:59.000
```

Whats the best way to get this?

Comment: Does `DateTime` have an `AddMonths` method? Does `DateTime` have a constructor where you could pass `1` as the day of the month? Have a think about how to combine those two things to get the thing you want.

Answer (score 7):

Here you go

```
DateTime mydate = DateTime.Today;

//2017-12-01 00:00:00.000
DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(mydate.Year, mydate.Month, 1).AddMonths(-14);

//2019-01-31 23:59:59.000
DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(mydate.Year, mydate.Month, 1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the date with `DateTime date = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-14).AddDays(-(DateTime.Today.Day - 1));`

`.AddMonths(-13)` yielded january 2018 for me